Partial fraction decomposition for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z\cos(\sqrt{z})}$
Note that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z\cos(\sqrt{z})}$ is meromorphic for any branch of $\sqrt{z}$ since $\cos$ is an even function. To reduce the problem to similar ones I have done in the past, I instead first consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\cos(z)}=f(z^2)$, which has poles at $\{0\}\cup\{\pi/2+\pi k, k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
Now, following the usual strategy I have seen, I consider the rectangle $R_N=\partial\{x+iy: |x|<(N+1)\pi, |y|<N\}$, with $N$ large enough that $z\in R_n$ and then by the Residue theorem, with $h(\eta)=\frac{1}{\eta-z}\frac{1}{\eta^2 \cos(\eta)}$,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{R_N} h(\eta)\,d\eta=\frac{1}{z^2\cos(z)}+\operatorname{Res}_{\eta=0}h(\eta)+ \sum_{k=-(N+1)}^N \operatorname{Res}_{\eta=\pi/2+\pi k}h(\eta).$$.
We compute the RHS to be, denoting $z_k=\pi/2+\pi k$
$$\frac{1}{z^2\cos(z)} - \frac{1}{z^2}- \sum_{k=-(N+1)}^N \frac{(-1)^k}{z_k^2(z-z_k)}.$$
I believe I can show that
$$\left| \int_{R_N} h(\eta)\,d\eta\right|\to 0 \text{ as }N\to\infty.$$
Thus, we have that
$$\frac{1}{z^2\cos(z)} - \frac{1}{z^2} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z_k^2(z-z_k)}.$$
I know I should be able to write the RHS purely as a function of $z^2$, but even after decomposing the sum as $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}a_k=a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k+a_{-k}$, I don't get an expression manifestly even in $z$.

LHS above is even so RHS must be even too - try and group together the terms with the same absolute value roots, one with plus and one with minus

I realized that since the sum is an even function from my application of the Residue theorem, I can just symmetrize it as follows:
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^k}{z_k^2(z-z_k)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{z_k^2(z-z_k)}+ \frac{(-1)^k}{z_k^2(-z-z_k)} = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{z_k (z^2-z_k^2)}.$$
Now, composing with square roots, it is clear that
$$\frac{1}{z\cos(\sqrt{z})}=\frac{1}{z}+ \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^k}{z_k (z-z_k^2)}$$
as meromorphic functions.
As Conrad mentions, I believe another strategy is to write the sum $\sum_{\mathbb{Z}} a_k$ as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k+a_{-k-1}$ combining terms with the same distance from the origin but the algebra looks a bit messier.
